# How do I extract and use the Carousel component from Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to use the Carousel from Bootstrap 4.0.0 to include in my site.  I don't want to include the rest of Bootstrap, I only want to use the Carousel component of the framework, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

I have the HTML written for the actual carousel, I just need to know how to extract the Carousel component from Bootstraps source files (including dependencies) and include them in my site.  Can you offer any suggestions on how I can do this please?

My site already includes jQuery, I simply need to know which files I need to include from the Bootstrap 4.0.0 source files.

Comment: If you do a custom build if Bootstrap, you can only include the carousel component. See the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 4):

1. First download **Bootstrap@4** [source-file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0-alpha.6/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist.zip).
2. Then extract `.zip` file.
3. Go to `js/dist`.
4. You will need two `js` files `carousel.js` and `util.js`.
5. You also need `carousel` `CSS`. You can use `bootstrap.css` or
   `bootstrap.min.css` or you can copy only **Bootstrap@4** `carousel CSS` from below `snippet`.

> Note: Bootstrap@4 `carousel.js` will not work without `util.js`. Load first `util.js` then `carousel.js`.

Below is `snippet` using **Bootstrap@4** `carousel.js` source file.

```js
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.6): util.js
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

var Util = function ($) {

/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Private TransitionEnd Helpers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

var transition = false;

var MAX_UID = 1000000;

var TransitionEndEvent = {
  WebkitTransition: 'webkitTransitionEnd',
  MozTransition: 'transitionend',
  OTransition: 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
  transition: 'transitionend'
};


function toType(obj) {
  return {}.toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

function isElement(obj) {
  return (obj[0] || obj).nodeType;
}

function getSpecialTransitionEndEvent() {
  return {
    bindType: transition.end,
    delegateType: transition.end,
    handle: function handle(event) {
      if ($(event.target).is(this)) {
        return event.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments); // eslint-disable-line prefer-rest-params
      }
      return undefined;
    }
  };
}

function transitionEndTest() {
  if (window.QUnit) {
    return false;
  }

  var el = document.createElement('bootstrap');

  for (var name in TransitionEndEvent) {
    if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
      return {
        end: TransitionEndEvent[name]
      };
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function transitionEndEmulator(duration) {
  var _this = this;

  var called = false;

  $(this).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, function () {
    called = true;
  });

  setTimeout(function () {
    if (!called) {
      Util.triggerTransitionEnd(_this);
    }
  }, duration);

  return this;
}

function setTransitionEndSupport() {
  transition = transitionEndTest();

  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator;

  if (Util.supportsTransitionEnd()) {
    $.event.special[Util.TRANSITION_END] = getSpecialTransitionEndEvent();
  }
}

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Public Util Api
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

var Util = {

  TRANSITION_END: 'bsTransitionEnd',

  getUID: function getUID(prefix) {
    do {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise
      prefix += ~~(Math.random() * MAX_UID); // "~~" acts like a faster Math.floor() here
    } while (document.getElementById(prefix));
    return prefix;
  },
  getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
    var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

    if (!selector) {
      selector = element.getAttribute('href') || '';
      selector = /^#[a-z]/i.test(selector) ? selector : null;
    }

    return selector;
  },
  reflow: function reflow(element) {
    return element.offsetHeight;
  },
  triggerTransitionEnd: function triggerTransitionEnd(element) {
    $(element).trigger(transition.end);
  },
  supportsTransitionEnd: function supportsTransitionEnd() {
    return Boolean(transition);
  },
  typeCheckConfig: function typeCheckConfig(componentName, config, configTypes) {
    for (var property in configTypes) {
      if (configTypes.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var expectedTypes = configTypes[property];
        var value = config[property];
        var valueType = value && isElement(value) ? 'element' : toType(value);

        if (!new RegExp(expectedTypes).test(valueType)) {
          throw new Error(componentName.toUpperCase() + ': ' + ('Option "' + property + '" provided type "' + valueType + '" ') + ('but expected type "' + expectedTypes + '".'));
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

setTransitionEndSupport();

return Util;
}(jQuery);
//# sourceMappingURL=util.js.map
var _typeof = typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol" ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; };

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.6): carousel.js
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

var Carousel = function ($) {

  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Constants
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  var NAME = 'carousel';
  var VERSION = '4.0.0-alpha.6';
  var DATA_KEY = 'bs.carousel';
  var EVENT_KEY = '.' + DATA_KEY;
  var DATA_API_KEY = '.data-api';
  var JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT = $.fn[NAME];
  var TRANSITION_DURATION = 600;
  var ARROW_LEFT_KEYCODE = 37; // KeyboardEvent.which value for left arrow key
  var ARROW_RIGHT_KEYCODE = 39; // KeyboardEvent.which value for right arrow key

  var Default = {
    interval: 5000,
    keyboard: true,
    slide: false,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true
  };

  var DefaultType = {
    interval: '(number|boolean)',
    keyboard: 'boolean',
    slide: '(boolean|string)',
    pause: '(string|boolean)',
    wrap: 'boolean'
  };

  var Direction = {
    NEXT: 'next',
    PREV: 'prev',
    LEFT: 'left',
    RIGHT: 'right'
  };

  var Event = {
    SLIDE: 'slide' + EVENT_KEY,
    SLID: 'slid' + EVENT_KEY,
    KEYDOWN: 'keydown' + EVENT_KEY,
    MOUSEENTER: 'mouseenter' + EVENT_KEY,
    MOUSELEAVE: 'mouseleave' + EVENT_KEY,
    LOAD_DATA_API: 'load' + EVENT_KEY + DATA_API_KEY,
    CLICK_DATA_API: 'click' + EVENT_KEY + DATA_API_KEY
  };

  var ClassName = {
    CAROUSEL: 'carousel',
    ACTIVE: 'active',
    SLIDE: 'slide',
    RIGHT: 'carousel-item-right',
    LEFT: 'carousel-item-left',
    NEXT: 'carousel-item-next',
    PREV: 'carousel-item-prev',
    ITEM: 'carousel-item'
  };

  var Selector = {
    ACTIVE: '.active',
    ACTIVE_ITEM: '.active.carousel-item',
    ITEM: '.carousel-item',
    NEXT_PREV: '.carousel-item-next, .carousel-item-prev',
    INDICATORS: '.carousel-indicators',
    DATA_SLIDE: '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]',
    DATA_RIDE: '[data-ride="carousel"]'
  };

  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Class Definition
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  var Carousel = function () {
    function Carousel(element, config) {
      _classCallCheck(this, Carousel);

      this._items = null;
      this._interval = null;
      this._activeElement = null;

      this._isPaused = false;
      this._isSliding = false;

      this._config = this._getConfig(config);
      this._element = $(element)[0];
      this._indicatorsElement = $(this._element).find(Selector.INDICATORS)[0];

      this._addEventListeners();
    }

    // getters

    // public

    Carousel.prototype.next = function next() {
      if (this._isSliding) {
        throw new Error('Carousel is sliding');
      }
      this._slide(Direction.NEXT);
    };

    Carousel.prototype.nextWhenVisible = function nextWhenVisible() {
      // Don't call next when the page isn't visible
      if (!document.hidden) {
        this.next();
      }
    };

    Carousel.prototype.prev = function prev() {
      if (this._isSliding) {
        throw new Error('Carousel is sliding');
      }
      this._slide(Direction.PREVIOUS);
    };

    Carousel.prototype.pause = function pause(event) {
      if (!event) {
        this._isPaused = true;
      }

      if ($(this._element).find(Selector.NEXT_PREV)[0] && Util.supportsTransitionEnd()) {
        Util.triggerTransitionEnd(this._element);
        this.cycle(true);
      }

      clearInterval(this._interval);
      this._interval = null;
    };

    Carousel.prototype.cycle = function cycle(event) {
      if (!event) {
        this._isPaused = false;
      }

      if (this._interval) {
        clearInterval(this._interval);
        this._interval = null;
      }

      if (this._config.interval && !this._isPaused) {
        this._interval = setInterval((document.visibilityState ? this.nextWhenVisible : this.next).bind(this), this._config.interval);
      }
    };

    Carousel.prototype.to = function to(index) {
      var _this = this;

      this._activeElement = $(this._element).find(Selector.ACTIVE_ITEM)[0];

      var activeIndex = this._getItemIndex(this._activeElement);

      if (index > this._items.length - 1 || index < 0) {
        return;
      }

      if (this._isSliding) {
        $(this._element).one(Event.SLID, function () {
          return _this.to(index);
        });
        return;
      }

      if (activeIndex === index) {
        this.pause();
        this.cycle();
        return;
      }

      var direction = index > activeIndex ? Direction.NEXT : Direction.PREVIOUS;

      this._slide(direction, this._items[index]);
    };

    Carousel.prototype.dispose = function dispose() {
      $(this._element).off(EVENT_KEY);
      $.removeData(this._element, DATA_KEY);

      this._items = null;
      this._config = null;
      this._element = null;
      this._interval = null;
      this._isPaused = null;
      this._isSliding = null;
      this._activeElement = null;
      this._indicatorsElement = null;
    };

    // private

    Carousel.prototype._getConfig = function _getConfig(config) {
      config = $.extend({}, Default, config);
      Util.typeCheckConfig(NAME, config, DefaultType);
      return config;
    };

    Carousel.prototype._addEventListeners = function _addEventListeners() {
      var _this2 = this;

      if (this._config.keyboard) {
        $(this._element).on(Event.KEYDOWN, function (event) {
          return _this2._keydown(event);
        });
      }

      if (this._config.pause === 'hover' && !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement)) {
        $(this._element).on(Event.MOUSEENTER, function (event) {
          return _this2.pause(event);
        }).on(Event.MOUSELEAVE, function (event) {
          return _this2.cycle(event);
        });
      }
    };

    Carousel.prototype._keydown = function _keydown(event) {
      if (/input|textarea/i.test(event.target.tagName)) {
        return;
      }

      switch (event.which) {
        case ARROW_LEFT_KEYCODE:
          event.preventDefault();
          this.prev();
          break;
        case ARROW_RIGHT_KEYCODE:
          event.preventDefault();
          this.next();
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    };

    Carousel.prototype._getItemIndex = function _getItemIndex(element) {
      this._items = $.makeArray($(element).parent().find(Selector.ITEM));
      return this._items.indexOf(element);
    };

    Carousel.prototype._getItemByDirection = function _getItemByDirection(direction, activeElement) {
      var isNextDirection = direction === Direction.NEXT;
      var isPrevDirection = direction === Direction.PREVIOUS;
      var activeIndex = this._getItemIndex(activeElement);
      var lastItemIndex = this._items.length - 1;
      var isGoingToWrap = isPrevDirection && activeIndex === 0 || isNextDirection && activeIndex === lastItemIndex;

      if (isGoingToWrap && !this._config.wrap) {
        return activeElement;
      }

      var delta = direction === Direction.PREVIOUS ? -1 : 1;
      var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this._items.length;

      return itemIndex === -1 ? this._items[this._items.length - 1] : this._items[itemIndex];
    };

    Carousel.prototype._triggerSlideEvent = function _triggerSlideEvent(relatedTarget, eventDirectionName) {
      var slideEvent = $.Event(Event.SLIDE, {
        relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
        direction: eventDirectionName
      });

      $(this._element).trigger(slideEvent);

      return slideEvent;
    };

    Carousel.prototype._setActiveIndicatorElement = function _setActiveIndicatorElement(element) {
      if (this._indicatorsElement) {
        $(this._indicatorsElement).find(Selector.ACTIVE).removeClass(ClassName.ACTIVE);

        var nextIndicator = this._indicatorsElement.children[this._getItemIndex(element)];

        if (nextIndicator) {
          $(nextIndicator).addClass(ClassName.ACTIVE);
        }
      }
    };

    Carousel.prototype._slide = function _slide(direction, element) {
      var _this3 = this;

      var activeElement = $(this._element).find(Selector.ACTIVE_ITEM)[0];
      var nextElement = element || activeElement && this._getItemByDirection(direction, activeElement);

      var isCycling = Boolean(this._interval);

      var directionalClassName = void 0;
      var orderClassName = void 0;
      var eventDirectionName = void 0;

      if (direction === Direction.NEXT) {
        directionalClassName = ClassName.LEFT;
        orderClassName = ClassName.NEXT;
        eventDirectionName = Direction.LEFT;
      } else {
        directionalClassName = ClassName.RIGHT;
        orderClassName = ClassName.PREV;
        eventDirectionName = Direction.RIGHT;
      }

      if (nextElement && $(nextElement).hasClass(ClassName.ACTIVE)) {
        this._isSliding = false;
        return;
      }

      var slideEvent = this._triggerSlideEvent(nextElement, eventDirectionName);
      if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        return;
      }

      if (!activeElement || !nextElement) {
        // some weirdness is happening, so we bail
        return;
      }

      this._isSliding = true;

      if (isCycling) {
        this.pause();
      }

      this._setActiveIndicatorElement(nextElement);

      var slidEvent = $.Event(Event.SLID, {
        relatedTarget: nextElement,
        direction: eventDirectionName
      });

      if (Util.supportsTransitionEnd() && $(this._element).hasClass(ClassName.SLIDE)) {

        $(nextElement).addClass(orderClassName);

        Util.reflow(nextElement);

        $(activeElement).addClass(directionalClassName);
        $(nextElement).addClass(directionalClassName);

        $(activeElement).one(Util.TRANSITION_END, function () {
          $(nextElement).removeClass(directionalClassName + ' ' + orderClassName).addClass(ClassName.ACTIVE);

          $(activeElement).removeClass(ClassName.ACTIVE + ' ' + orderClassName + ' ' + directionalClassName);

          _this3._isSliding = false;

          setTimeout(function () {
            return $(_this3._element).trigger(slidEvent);
          }, 0);
        }).emulateTransitionEnd(TRANSITION_DURATION);
      } else {
        $(activeElement).removeClass(ClassName.ACTIVE);
        $(nextElement).addClass(ClassName.ACTIVE);

        this._isSliding = false;
        $(this._element).trigger(slidEvent);
      }

      if (isCycling) {
        this.cycle();
      }
    };

    // static

    Carousel._jQueryInterface = function _jQueryInterface(config) {
      return this.each(function () {
        var data = $(this).data(DATA_KEY);
        var _config = $.extend({}, Default, $(this).data());

        if ((typeof config === 'undefined' ? 'undefined' : _typeof(config)) === 'object') {
          $.extend(_config, config);
        }

        var action = typeof config === 'string' ? config : _config.slide;

        if (!data) {
          data = new Carousel(this, _config);
          $(this).data(DATA_KEY, data);
        }

        if (typeof config === 'number') {
          data.to(config);
        } else if (typeof action === 'string') {
          if (data[action] === undefined) {
            throw new Error('No method named "' + action + '"');
          }
          data[action]();
        } else if (_config.interval) {
          data.pause();
          data.cycle();
        }
      });
    };

    Carousel._dataApiClickHandler = function _dataApiClickHandler(event) {
      var selector = Util.getSelectorFromElement(this);

      if (!selector) {
        return;
      }

      var target = $(selector)[0];

      if (!target || !$(target).hasClass(ClassName.CAROUSEL)) {
        return;
      }

      var config = $.extend({}, $(target).data(), $(this).data());
      var slideIndex = this.getAttribute('data-slide-to');

      if (slideIndex) {
        config.interval = false;
      }

      Carousel._jQueryInterface.call($(target), config);

      if (slideIndex) {
        $(target).data(DATA_KEY).to(slideIndex);
      }

      event.preventDefault();
    };

    _createClass(Carousel, null, [{
      key: 'VERSION',
      get: function get() {
        return VERSION;
      }
    }, {
      key: 'Default',
      get: function get() {
        return Default;
      }
    }]);

    return Carousel;
  }();

  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * Data Api implementation
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  $(document).on(Event.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector.DATA_SLIDE, Carousel._dataApiClickHandler);

  $(window).on(Event.LOAD_DATA_API, function () {
    $(Selector.DATA_RIDE).each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this);
      Carousel._jQueryInterface.call($carousel, $carousel.data());
    });
  });

  /**
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   * jQuery
   * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */

  $.fn[NAME] = Carousel._jQueryInterface;
  $.fn[NAME].Constructor = Carousel;
  $.fn[NAME].noConflict = function () {
    $.fn[NAME] = JQUERY_NO_CONFLICT;
    return Carousel._jQueryInterface;
  };

  return Carousel;
}(jQuery);
//# sourceMappingURL=carousel.js.map
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
  }
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)) or (transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0))) {
  .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
  }
}

.carousel-item.active,
.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

@media (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-item-next,
  .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-item-prev,
  .active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

@supports ((-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)) or (transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0))) {
  .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
  .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-item-next,
  .active.carousel-item-right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-item-prev,
  .active.carousel-item-left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  width: 15%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.carousel-control-prev:focus, .carousel-control-prev:hover,
.carousel-control-next:focus,
.carousel-control-next:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.carousel-control-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  right: 0;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon,
.carousel-control-next-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
          background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M4 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M1.5 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
          flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.carousel-indicators li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
}

.carousel-indicators li::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.img-fluid{
height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.d-block{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x500" width="100%" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x500" width="100%" alt="First slide">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/800x500" width="100%" alt="First slide">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
```